# Wait for channel close

Tags: kotlin, channel

I have a channel that I only use to convey that a connection was closed. I figured a `Unit` channel which I then close on disconnect would be the most appropriate. Simplified example:

```
class Connection {
  val disconnect = Channel<Unit>(1, BufferOverflow.DROP_LATEST)
  fun connect() {
    backingConnection.disconnectCallback = {
      disconnect.close()
    }
    backingConnection.connect()
  }
}
```

Now the question is how to wait for this channel to close. Here are two options, both look a bit verbose:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    try {
        connection.disconnect.receive()
    } catch (ignore: Exception) {}
    finish()
}
```

or

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    @Suppress("ControlFlowWithEmptyBody")
    for (dummy in connection.disconnect) {}
    finish()
}
```

Are there better options?

Answer (score 2):

I just found there is a `receiveCatching()` method I can use for this purpose:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    connection.disconnect.receiveCatching()
    finish()
}
```